# JCE cannot authenticate the provider ABA

Tags: java, cryptography, jce

I have to run a quite old programcode which uses ABA-provider for JCE.
All classes are available in the source folder. However, a *NoSuchProviderException* occures: "JCE cannot authenticate the provider ABA".

I found some related topics in the forums but they coulnd't help me out.

This is what I did:

```
ABAProvider prov = new ABAProvider();
Security.addProvider(prov);
```

In debug-mode *prov* is initialized but this throws the exception:

```
keyFactory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance( "DES", "ABA" );
```

I hope this information might help you to help me :)
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ABA seems to be a cleanroom implementation of Java JCE. Just remove the dependency and use the providers supplied in your favorite runtime

Signing certificates for Java have to be renewed. You cannot use an old certificate on a new version of Java. So the signature on the provider has likely expired.

More information [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/crypto/HowToImplAProvider.html#Step6):

> The next step is to request a code-signing certificate so that you can use it to sign your provider prior to testing. The certificate will be good for both testing and production. **It will be valid for 5 years**.

The usefulness of DES for most cryptographic operations (possibly except creating 3 key TDES) has "expired" as well.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I'm a bit confused: How do I sign the certificate? (and which certificate?)

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/crypto/HowToImplAProvider.html#Step6